# Why closing square bracket "]" doesn't require escaping in regex?

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

Consider the array:

```
new Pattern[] {Pattern.compile("\\["),Pattern.compile("\\]") };
```

Intellij IDEA tells me that `\\` is redundant and tells me to replace this with `]` e.g. the result is:

```
new Pattern[] {Pattern.compile("\\["),Pattern.compile("]") };
```

Why in the first `Pattern.compile("\\[")` is the `\\` OK, but for the second it is redundant?

Comment: The regex engine sees `[` as the start of a character class, so if you mean the literal `[` character, it needs escaping. Presumably it won't read `]` as the end of a character class unless you are in the middle of defining a character class, so it does not need escaping in this situation.

Answer (score 18):

The `]` symbol is not a special regex operator outside the character class if there is no corresponding unescaped `[` before it. Only special characters require escaping. A `[` is a special regex operator outside a character class (as it may mark the starting point of a character class). Once the Java regular expression engine sees an unescaped `[` in the pattern, it knows there must be a `]` to close the character class ahead. Whether it is escaped or not, it does not matter for the engine. If there is no opening `[` in the expression, the `]` is treated as a mere literal `]` symbol. So, `[abc]` will match `a`, `b` or `c`, and `\[abc]` or `\[abc\]` will match `[abc]` literal character sequence.

So, the `[` should be escaped always, and `]` does not have to be escaped *outside a character class*.

When used *inside a character class*, both `[` and `]` must be escaped inside a Java regular expression as they may form intersection/subtraction patterns, *unless* the `]` appears at the beginning of a character class (i.e. `"[a]".replaceAll("[]\\[]", "")` [returns](https://ideone.com/q9OGTm) `a`).

**Other regex flavors**

[icu](/questions/tagged/icu) [onigmo](/questions/tagged/onigmo) - In ICU and Onigmo regex flavor, `]` behaves the same as in Java regex flavor. Languages affected: [swift](/questions/tagged/swift), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), [r](/questions/tagged/r) (*`stringr`*), [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin), [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy).

[pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) [boost](/questions/tagged/boost) [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) [re2](/questions/tagged/re2) [python](/questions/tagged/python) [posix](/questions/tagged/posix) - In Boost, PCRE, `]` is not a special char (i.e. needs no escaping) outside a character class, and is a special char (=needs escaping) inside a character class (where it does not need escaping only if it is the first char in the character class.) It is not an error to escape it everywhere where it is supposted to match a literal `]` char. Languages/tools affected: [php](/questions/tagged/php), [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)/[vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net)/etc., [python](/questions/tagged/python), [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), [r](/questions/tagged/r) (both default base R TRE and PCRE enabled with `"perl=TRUE"`), [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl), [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets).

[ecmascript](/questions/tagged/ecmascript) - In ECMAScript flavors, `]` is not special outside a character class, while `[` is special outside a character class. Inside a character class, `]` must ALWAYS be escaped, even if it is the first char in the character class. `[` inside a character class is not special, but escaping it is an error if the regexp is compiled with the `/u` flag (in JavaScript). So, be careful here. Languages affected: [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [dart](/questions/tagged/dart), [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) (which uses JavaScript).

Answer (score 7):

The `]` is considered metacharacter **only when it is used to close [character set](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)** `[...]`.

If before `]` there is no unclosed and unescaped opening square bracket `[` then `]` is as simple literal which doesn't require escaping (but *allows* it, which is why your IDE gives you *"warning"* instead of *error*).

---

Only place when you may want to escape `]` is *inside character set* when you want regex to treat is as simple symbol instead of metacharacter which is *closing* character set.

For instance regex like `"[ab\\]cd]"` represents `a` or `b` or `]` or `c` or `d`.

BUT similar regex can be also written like `[a-d]|]`. Notice that last `]` is not "special" because there is no *opened* character class before it. So it is considered as literal -  character without special meaning, which means it doesn't require escaping.